NGINX proxy_pass, proxy_cache & CORS not working
Why is it that when adding add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always; to allow any CORS request, caching stops working in nginx?
What is the solution?
    proxy_cache_path /tmp/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=dokku:10m inactive=60m use_temp_path=off;
    add_header X-Cache-Status \$upstream_cache_status;

    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            # Proxy
            proxy_pass  http://0.0.0.0:3000/;

            # CACHE
            proxy_cache dokku; 

            # CORS
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always; # <-- Offending line
        }
    }

